# Javascript for-loop with certain step

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, typescript

I have an array with `100` elements, I want to take an element from 10th to 15th `(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)`, than from 20th to 25th, than from 30th to 35th, from 40th to 45th and from 50th to 55th, so I always have a `gap= 4` and store to a new 2D value. I found out how to store to 2D array, but how could I make this gap?

this is how I could make a chunk of size 6 (because I always need first six element of "decade")

```
var newArr = [];
while(arr.length) newArr.push(arr.splice(0,6));
```

or

```
function splitArray(array, part) {
    var tmp = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i += part) {
        tmp.push(array.slice(i, i + part));
    }
    return tmp;
}

console.log(splitArray(m1, 6));
```

But first of all I have to make a new array of elements (10-15, 20-25 and so on...). How could I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function needs a separate parameter for the stride and the size of each part. It uses the stride when incrementing the `for` loop variable, and the size when taking the slice.

```js
function splitArray(array, stride, size) {
    var tmp = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i += stride) {
        tmp.push(array.slice(i, i + size));
    }
    return tmp;
}

var m1 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    m1.push(i);
}
console.log(splitArray(m1, 10, 6));
```

Comment: @AnnaF Please mark as answer if it answers your question

Answer (score 1):

A [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) removes the need to store intermediate results. Introducing an offset argument allows you to skip the first five values `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`:

```js
function* splitArray(array, stride, size, offset = 0) {
  for (let i = offset; i < array.length; i += stride) {
    yield array.slice(i, i + size);
  }
}

// Example:
const array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25];
console.log(...splitArray(array, 10, 6, 10));
```

Apart from those particularities, this implementation is identical to [Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44710330/1647737).